# When should I throw `ObjectDisposedException`?

Tags: .net, clr

Jeffry Richter says (*in CLR via C# Edition 4, P.534*) that all methods and properties in a class implementing `IDisposable` should throw `ObjectDisposedException` explicitly.

This makes sense, but I've never actually seen it done in the wild.

Is this a recommendation that's just not followed because developers don't know (or don't care) or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: It seems a lot of the framework classes only throw it when you call methods (or properties) that require specific resources which are no longer available when disposed. For example if you try to write to a closed socket, of course they throw. But if you only set the `ForeColor` of a disposed `TextBox` they seem to think an exception would be too much (though actually after setting the color it should be repainted, and that should throw...but it doesn't).

Comment: [`TCPClient`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPClient.cs,943f9db3a7511918) as an example certainly seems to throw it. But *all* methods/properties may be too strong a recommendation. E.g. most guidance suggests you should *allow* multiple `Dispose` calls and properties that allow the caller to *determine* the current state of an object are generally not frowned upon.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Aye, certainally `Dispose` itself should throw any exception.  Having all callers explicitly check the state feels like a lot of noise and heartache, especially when multiple threads are working.  Would the pie-in-the-sky, _correct_ solution to have the CLR throw the exception if any operation is performed on a disposed object?  I can't think of any instance where it would be valid to even perform a `get`.

Comment: @RenéVogt Feels a bit like `Application Exception`.  Good idea, but not followed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly throw it when a member of your type cannot function because a resource it depends on is disposed.

- In many cases, your Type may be wrapping an IDisposable instance.  In which case, you can simply call members of the wrapped IDisposable instance, and let it be responsible for throwing `ObjectDisposedException`.
- But there may be cases when you want to throw it explicitly.  For example, if your Dispose method sets a wrapped IDisposable instance to null, you will need to throw the execption explicitly because you no longer have an instance to delegate it to.
- Or if your IDisposable class directly owns an unmanaged resource, it will need to explicitly throw ObjectDisposedException if the unmanaged resource has been released.
- Finally a Member that executes significant logic before calling a wrapped IDisposable member might want to "fail fast", and throw ObjectDisposedException rather than executing such logic unnecessarily.
- Members that don't rely on a wrapped IDisposable instance or unmanaged resource don't need to throw ObjectDisposedException if it is more appropriate not to do so.
- I don't think Jeffrey Richter's advice that *all* members of an IDisposable class should throw when disposed makes sense.  There are plenty of examples in the Framework of IDisposable classes that have members that don't throw when disposed.  E.g.

  - `FileStream.Name` will return the name passed to a FileStream's constructor, even if the FileStream is disposed, because it doesn't need to access the stream to return the name.
  - A System.Windows.Form will allow access to many members after it's been disposed.  So if you've shown a dialog modally and disposed the Form, you can still access the user input that's been entered in the Form.

Comment: And a DirectorySearcher allows you to use it to search directories after being disposed. Wonderful!